# Sending a web request with a python script to select a specific radio button on a web page

Tags: python

I have to test an internal web page.
The web page contains text fields, buttons, and radio buttons.
Based on a specific radio button selected another sub-form is displayed in the web page.

I'm using urllib2, and some of its modules, to successfully connect to the web server and perform some actions.

However, not able to select the radio button, via a POST from the python script, I'm not able to proceed with the test automation.

Reading some of the online posts about selecting radio buttons I read that some people are using "mechanize". I'm not familiar with this. Is there another specific module in urllib2 that would allow me to send a POST request to select a specific radio button.

Roland

Comment: A radio button is nothing special. You just set the `POST` to send `nameOfTheRadioButtonGroup: selectedRadioButtonValue`.

Answer (score 0):

They are referring to this python module: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/. You can emulate the selected radio button in the form by posting the form properly with `urllib2`. Discussed in this post: [urllib2: submitting a form and then redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507170/urllib2-submitting-a-form-and-then-redirecting).

Imagine you have a form with a radio input like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="something" />
```

The post body would be: `something=1`.

Answer (score 0):

If we have for example this HTML code:

`<input type="radio" name="register" value="0" checked="checked"> "Yes it's my password"`

then you must put in your payload:

```
payload["register"]="Yes it's my password"
```